# HttpVerbAttribute routing for REST APIs, what is the use of Name property

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

while relying on http verb based attribute routing for my api controllers/actions, we can use something like this:

```
[HttpGet("info/{id?}", Name = nameof(GetSomeInfo))]
public ActionResult<string> GetSomeInfo(string id, string lastName)
{
   return Ok(id + " Prerak " + lastName);
}
```

The call that goes in the fiddler looks like following:

```
GET /WeatherForecast/info/23?lastName=myLastName
```

But I am not sure what is the use of the Name property we set in the `httpGetAttribute` as following:

```
[HttpGet("info/{id?}", Name = nameof(GetSomeInfo))]
```

I am reading this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.httpgetattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0

But, it just says following, and I am confused what is the use , if the name we are setting up here is not showing in the url generation, the url is always formed using the route template,`"info/{id?}"` for example.

> Gets the route name. The route name can be used to generate a link
> using a specific route, instead of relying on selection of a route
> based on the given set of route values.
>
> (Inherited from HttpMethodAttribute)

Please, I need help in understanding this or kindly point me to the right resource.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to generate a link to an action, say your `GetSomeInfo` endpoint, what do you do?

You can generate it by hand using string interpolation

```cs
var url = $"/info/{myId}";
```

While that works, what happens if you change `[HttpGet("info/{id?}")]` to something else, do you make changes to everywhere where you used it? Or what if changes dynamically per request (depending on the domain, language etc.)?

To overcome this issue, you can optionally give a name to your action, then reference it when building a link:

Inside a controller / middleware / Razor page, you can inject a `LinkGenerator` instance:

```cs
var links = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<LinkGenerator>();
var href = links.GetUriByName(
    HttpContext,
    nameof(MyController.GetSomeInfo), // this gives you "GetSomeInfo"
    new { id = 123 }
);
```

or inside a Razor template you can use `<a asp-route"..." />` helper tag.

```
<a asp-route="GetSomeInfo" asp-route-id="123">Get Info</a>
```

Additionally, it populates OpenAPI `operationId` metadata of that action, which helps clients generate code to access your endpoint with the name you give, instead of the name of the action (which might not indicate what it actually does, as is the case with `GetSomeInfo`).

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-name):

> Route names can be used to generate a URL based on a specific route. Route names:
>
> - Have no impact on the URL matching behavior of routing.
> - Are only used for URL generation.
>   Route names must be unique application-wide.
>
> Contrast the preceding code with the conventional default route, which defines the id parameter as optional `({id?})`. The ability to precisely specify APIs has advantages, such as allowing `/products` and `/products/5` to be dispatched to different actions.

Reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-name
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-5.0